# What is the English culinary term for the meat in a dish?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

For example, the ground meat in Bolognese that is absent in Puttanesca. Or when you decided to make salad "sinful" you added pork rinds to it.

Comment: Chefs call it the ***protein***

Comment: Trick question - *meat* is a culinary term :-)

Comment: Belongs on [cooking.se]

Comment: @Kris: It's fine here.

Comment: @ruakh What was *that*?

Comment: @ruakh Look at the "answers" and see what happens when asked anywhere.

Comment: I wouldn't refer to pork rinds (fried pork skin) as 'meat'. Sure, it is an animal product, but informally and culinarily it would be very strange to think of it as meat.

Answer (score 4):

In culinary-specific terms, it's referred to as a [**protein**](http://chefsblade.monster.com/training/articles/1214-kitchen-jargon-glossary):

> Generic term for the protein component of a dish—meat, fish, poultry, or even “meat substitute” like tofu or seitan. Does not refer to eggs.

Of course, chefs *do* simply say **meat**.

In standard English, although it would not be common, you could ask that a [*carnivorous*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carnivorous) element be added to the dish.

> **1** : subsisting or feeding on animal tissues